# Why the ampersand at the end of the truncated quote of my question on the recent questions page?

Tags: support, design

My recent [question post](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/45319/12102) contains no ampersand character "&" but one is displayed when I view the recent questions page https://space.stackexchange.com/questions

I don't recall seeing this before and I don't see any other questions with this character at the end of the truncated quote.

Does this have some significance?

Annotated screenshot with ampersand indicated with a red arrow:

> [image: Annotated screenshot with ampersand indicated with a red arrow]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Conjecture - the next character is a double quote mark:

[image: Screenshot of the question "What is the difference between “body drag”, “frictional drag” and “pressure drag” for astronaut or aerobot atmospheric locomotion in microgravity?" with a quote circled.]

And, when converted to [ASCII](http://www.techdictionary.com/ascii.html), the next character would be an "&"... something like "`&quot;`", "`&#034;`" or "`&#147;`" depending on if it's curly or not.

Viewing the page source, you find this:

[image: Screenshot of the page source of the question, which reveals the correct answer - "&quot;", which is circled.]

Which seems to prove the conjecture out.

Comment: I did a quick edit and confirmed that changing the double quote to an "x" causes the ampersand to disappear: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gnRKW.png and https://i.stack.imgur.com/TmnBW.png (have since rolled back)

Comment: That’s not really about ASCII. `"` is still part of the ASCII range; `&quot;` is HTML encoding. That website seems to have a misunderstanding. Even then, the curly `“` and `”` are not actually encoded in the response, but the `"` are, even though “… `by "swimming" in` …” would’ve been valid HTML, too.